# Booting from USB via PXE

Tags: macos, mac, usb, bootloader, pxe

I have a computer where I am only able to network boot. I need to boot from a USB drive, is there anything I can use to network boot and then boot from USB?

Another solution would be to PXE-boot a Hackintosh installer.

Edit:
The bios is locked so I am only able to boot from the internal SSD or networkboot. Secure boot is disabled. I have already tried installing Ubuntu and KDE Neon so I know that works.

Comment: Please clarify why you cannot boot from USB directly. Is the BIOS perhaps locked? Is the PC too old to be capable of USB boot?

Comment: Please also note that running macOS on non-Apple hardware is off-topic on Super User.

Comment: I have added extra info to the post now, the post isn't necessarily for macOS although that is what I'm gonna use it for :)

Comment: If you own the system, you could always try and reset the firmware (BIOS/UEFI). This should remove any and all passwords. Using PXE, you boot legacy style. To boot with UEFI, you need to use UEFI NetBoot, which is more complicated to set up.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cmos in various ways but nothing resets the password, so I'm stuck with networkboot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) and PXE boot/install whatever you want
(I'm related to Serva development).